# Проблема с переводом массива json в массив php

Tags: php, json

Нужно отредактировать массив json и внести в него елемент $spi из инпута через пост.
Проблема заключается в том, что у меня не получается достать массив из teacher.json в переменную $content, хотя в интернете видел пример, где все было так же и работало.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['uchitel']))
    {
        echo "Получено письмо: " . $_POST['uchitel'] . PHP_EOL;
        spi($_POST['uchitel']);
    }
    function spi($spis)
    {
        echo "Есть функция spi" . PHP_EOL;
        $file = file_get_contents("teacher.json");
        $content = json_decode($file, true);
        print_r($content);
        $content['teachers'] = $spis;
        file_put_contents("teacher.txt", $content);
        //echo "записано в файл " . "<pre>" . fread(fopen("teacher.txt", "r"), filesize("teacher.txt")) . "</pre>";
    }

?>
```

Прошу камнями не кидаться, я только начал изучать php и тем более ангуляр.
в teacher.txt записывается только то, что ввожу в инпут (т.е. $spi)
вот teacher.json:

```
"teachers":
{
    "name":"Пачгина Алевтина Афанасьевна"
},
{
    "name":"Арсентьева Татьяна Ивановна"
},
{
    "name":"Сайдакова Ольга Владимировна"
},
{
    "name":"Коссихина Людмила Юрьевна"
}
```

Comment: невалидный json (http://json.parser.online.fr/ - для проверки)

Comment: непонятно из кода как вам такой файл получить удалось. `file_put_contents("teacher.txt", json_encode($content));` в описании функции можете посмотреть вские ключи, например, чтоб буквы в коды не переделывал

Comment: что б лучше понимать как выводить массив, используйте print_r тот же или var_dump в обвертке тега <pre> </pre> и тогда сразу станет ясно, какой где ключ и как его выводить.